# Django-Executing Python code in HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I have a python script written up that returns a list of values from a database. I want to incorporate that script into my django website that I have created. I have an html file right now in my templates folder that has dictionary values hardcoded but how do I replace the dictionary hardcoded material with the script, lets call it values.py

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dropDown = [" ", "Run1", "Run2", "Trail1", "Trail2"];
    var dropDownID = [" ", "111111", "222222", "333333", "444444", "555555"];
    $("#dropDown").select2({
        data: dropDown
    });

    $("#dropDown").change(function() {
        $("#dropdownID").val(dropDownID[$("#dropDown option:selected").index()]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where's your python script or values.py code ?, please post more info so we can help

Comment: @jsanchezs the python code I put into my project directory and then in a folder called "templatetags" inside is values.py and init.py

Comment: Yeah, tags are indeed the way to achieve that but post your python code in the question so we can figure out how it works and understand exactly what you need to guide you through

Comment: @jsanchezs its a rather long script and is connected to other features within the database, if you can just guide me to how to even submit a python script into django that would be appreciated. Lets just use a simple dictionary one like the hardcoded above or we can forget about dictionary and just do a simple hello world script

Comment: @VisualExtasy I think question it's quite different from the code you posted, anyhow i posted you a basic example of how tags work. remember to mark as correct the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As we talked, tags are the way to achieve that....Let's say you want to do a simple "Hello world" tag, this would be your tag.py code :

**tag.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def hello_world(name):
    salute = 'Hello' + name
    
    return salute
```

As you see, you got all the python code there, depending on what you need you may need to import models or anything else from database...assuming you got all that in order as you say, you just create the function, process all code you need and return something (dictionary of data in your case to iterate in template), but for this simple example just a string with the name.

Then, inside your template you load your tag file, and call the function sending the specific parameter to use it later as i show you here :

**Template.html**

```
{% load tag %}
<div id="id_div">
    {% hello_world 'Foo' as salute_text %}
    <strong> {{ salute_text }} </strong>
</div>
```

Hope it helps to clarify!!

Comment: I get a tag.py is not a registered tag library error.

Comment: Did you tried my code from zero or are you using your file called values.py ?, remember in this example tag.py should be the name of the file and it should be in templatetags directory.

Comment: Yea I used yours tag.py in templatetags directory and then in the calling its {% load tag.py %}

Comment: Sorry, it has no '.py' at the end, i updated my answer, it's : {{ load tag }}

Comment: it works :D, but do you mind explaining it to me like what is always required when doing template tags and what is just for this example only. I'm assumming the template import and register = template.Library has to be done everytime

Comment: Sure, template.Library  and @register.assignment_tag it's needed always so it be a valid tag library, the module must contain a module-level variable named register that is a template.Library instance, in which all the tags and filters are registered. Also as a said before, model imports or calls you may need in your python code...Glad to help, remember to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: in your example youre calling the script hello_world and adding food to the name as it, then putting it into header 3 correct? Why is salute = Hello + name?

Comment: hello_world function receives a parameter called name, i just call that function inside the template sending it 'Foo' as that name and later i concatenate a salute string to return

Comment: so can would I be able to import a 500 line python code into a template tag or just function definitions?

Comment: @VisualExstasy The idea it's to call functions. many of few python code lines are based on what you need to create or achieve with them.

Comment: sorry I'm sort of confused. I have a python code with 600+ lines of code includes connecting to the database, sorting the results, displaying results ext. Would I import all that into template tag and then add the import and register template tag and then put the script in my html to call it?

Comment: Don worry. No, as i told you before, tags are most of the time used to call functions in a template when you need python code there somehow....for everything you're saying you use the model and views django system. See the documentation here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/